# expressed as a sum of elements of $A$ is dense in $(0,\infty)$??

Tags: real-analysis

If $0$ is a limit point of a set $A\subset (0,\infty)$, then is it true that the set of all $x\in (0,\infty)$ that can be expressed as a sum of (not necessarily distinct) elements of $A$ is dense in $(0,\infty)$?

I think this is not true, for example: $A=\{1/n^2 : n\in \mathbb{N} \}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $0<a<b<\infty$. Choose $x>0$ such that $x \in A$ and $\frac {b-a} x >1$. This is possible because $0$ is a limit point of $A$. Every interval whose length exceeds $1$ contains an integer. Let $n \in (\frac a x ,\frac b x)$. Then $n$ is positive and $nx \in (a,b)$. But $nx$ is  sum of elements of $A$ and so the proof is complete.

Comment: Is it also true when condition only distinct ??

Comment: @GCR No. Your example works in this case. Sums of distinct numbers from $\{\frac 1 {n^{2}}\}$ are all less then or equal to $\frac {\pi^{2}} 6$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is true. Let $\varepsilon > 0$. As $0$ is a limit point of $A$, there is an $a \in A$ such that $a < \varepsilon$. Now consider the set $B := \{na : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, which consinsts only of sums of elements in $A$. By construction, for every $x \in (0,\infty)$ there is a $b \in B$ such that $|x-b| < \varepsilon$. As $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, we conclude that the set of elements that can be constructed by summing elements in $A$ must be dense in $(0,\infty)$. In fact, the set $\{na : n \in \mathbb{N}, a \in A\}$ is dense in $(0,\infty)$.